# Is it possible to select the topmost window in another monitor with AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

I know you can select the topmost window on the window the cursor is in with `MouseGetPos, _mouseX, _mouseY, _winID`, but I want to be able to consistently grab the topmost window in my second monitor, regardless of whether my mouse is in my first, second, third, or fourth monitor. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I did have a function to return the number of the monitor the program I want to switch to is (almost always my second monitor) but apparently `MonitorGet` is a function that doesn't actually exist despite AutoHotKey literally having documentation for it. I honestly don't know if I'll ever be able to get this script running the way I want it to given how incredibly limited (and even broken) AutoHotKey appears to be.

Comment: What are the coordinates of each monitor? You could use them to activate the topmost window.

Comment: See  [example](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SysGet.htm#Monitor).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
; Press F1 to activate the last active window in the second monitor:

F1::
SysGet, Mon2, Monitor, 2
list := ""
WinGet, id, list
Loop, %id%
{
    this_ID := id%A_Index%
    WinGetClass, Class, ahk_id %this_ID%
        If (Class = "")
            continue
    WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %this_ID%
        If (title = "")
            continue
    If !IsWindow(WinExist("ahk_id" . this_ID))
            continue
    WinGetPos, X,,,, ahk_id %this_ID%
        if (X < Mon2Left)
            continue
    WinActivate, ahk_id %this_ID%, ,2
            break
}
return

;-----------------------------------------------------------------
; Check whether the target window is activation target
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
IsWindow(hWnd){
    WinGet, dwStyle, Style, ahk_id %hWnd%
    if ((dwStyle&0x08000000) || !(dwStyle&0x10000000)) {
        return false
    }
    WinGet, dwExStyle, ExStyle, ahk_id %hWnd%
    if (dwExStyle & 0x00000080) {
        return false
    }
    WinGetClass, szClass, ahk_id %hWnd%
    if (szClass = "TApplication") {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Appologies for taking so long. I'm trying to work this in with my solution. Once I do that, I'll mark this as the accepted answer while giving an answer of my own that would have been what I might have expected had I bothered to add far more information into my question. As you can probably tell, I was very frustrated when I wrote that question. In the meantime, I think I understand the first part of your code, but if you want to add comments explaining what the specific bits you're working with in `IsWindow(hWnd)` control/reference, that could speed up my working your code into mine.